# return type issue with IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq, types, ienumerable

I am working on a linq method and cannot seem to get the return type to match the method signature.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> RunQuery(XDocument doc)
{
    var data = from b in doc.Descendants("Company")
               where b.Attribute("name").Value == "CompanyA"
               from y in b.Descendants("Shirt")
               from z in y.Descendants("Size")
               select new
               {
                   color = y.Attribute("id").Value,
                   price = z.Value
               };

    return data;
}
```

Comment: new {...} will create an anonymous type, not a KeyValuePair.

Comment: try to return data.ToDiscionary(k=>k.color, k=>k.price);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create KeyValuePairs.

```
...
select new KeyValuePair(y.Attribute("id").Value, z.Value)
```

Comment: Ah. I new it would be something simple. Any benefits of key value pair over a dictionary?

Comment: @LanceCollins `Any benefits of key value pair over a dictionary` - not so much. `IEnumerable` is just a sequence of elements, so you won't have constant access time, as to be compared to `IDictionary<string, string>`, so I suggest to change method signature and return this type

Answer (score 1):

You can make your query much sorter. Note I've removed `from y in b.Descendants("Shirt")`, because `Descendants` parse the whole xml node including all it's descendants up to lowest level. This query will return `Dictionary<string, string>`, which implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, so you don't need to change method signature, but I strongly recommend to do this, because client's won't be able to access dictionary elements with constant time

```
return doc.Descendants("Company")
          .Where(node => node.Attribute("name").Value == "CompanyA")
          .Descendants("Size")
          .ToDictionary(node => node.Attribute("id").Value,
                        node => node.Value);
```